# Error: Couldn't establish a secure connection on android 4.4.2

Tags: android, ssl

I am trying to access my website from android 4.4.2 mobile browser. But I am getting this error: "Couldn't establish a secure connection". I think it is related to SSL. I checked my website on https://www.ssllabs.com. I got the below results:

[image]

[image]

Any Help?

Comment: Are you serving all intermediate certificates? The SSLLabs report will indicate any missing intermediates.

Comment: So Should I serve TLS1.0? SSL2 & 3 certificates?

Comment: No. What is your SSL Labs score? Do you see any warnings in the report?

Comment: Overall score is A. No Warnings. I tried the website on another mobile with android 4.4.2 and it worked.